# How to add a dot down below navigation bar

Tags: css

I'd like to add a blue dot down below the menu. (Only with current page)
[image]
How should I do with CSS?

https://dayup5.website/home/

Please help, Thank you.

```
<Nav>
<m1>首頁</m1><br><m2>Top</m2>
</Nav>
```

```
#Nav{
    text-align:center;
  line-height:1;
}

m1{
    font-size:14px;
    letter-spacing:6px;
    font-weight:lighter;
}

m2{
    font-size:8px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
        -webkit-transform:scale(0.67);
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:lighter
}
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of "active" class or attribute on the currently active item? If so, you can add the dot using the `::after` pseudo-element on the active item

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've update the css currently. Please have a look.

Comment: you need a way to tell which of the items corresponds to the current page. We would need to see more of your code to be able to help you with that...

Comment: Thank you. https://dayup5.website/home/
This website is builded with Elementor.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using css ::before or ::after pseudo element

```css
m1 {

  position:relative;
}

m1::before {
  background: blue;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-2.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<Nav>
  <m1>首頁</m1><br>
</Nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, James. Is it possible to make the blue dot display only on current page ?

Comment: do you mean, only to apply to the "首頁", if yes, then just assign an id to it and change all the property to the id inside of `m1`

Comment: Thanks. Only apply to the page which I'm viewing. For example, when I was viewing the home page, there will be a dot under "HOME" in the menu.

Comment: @Patrick, apply the css in a class and remove the class name if the url is not homepage

Comment: Hi James.
Blue dot under "HOME" when I viewing homepage, blue dot only display under "DEMO" when I viewing demo page etc. .